# UPDATE SET values ignoring set ordering

Tags: mysql, update

I'm trying to update 2 rows at once, I want to:

1) Set coupon.start (datetime) to the original account.vipExpires (datetime)

2) Add coupon.days (int) to account.vipExpires (datetime)

3) Set coupon.end (datetime) to the new value of account.vipExpires after coupon.days have been added

```
UPDATE accounts a, coupons c
SET c.start = a.vipExpires,
    a.vipExpires =  DATE_ADD(a.vipExpires, INTERVAL c.days DAY),
    c.end = a.vipExpires
WHERE a.id = 1 AND c.id = 1;
```

The result I'm getting is:

c.start, a.vipExpires, c.end ALL end up as the new datetime with the added days.

How do I make c.start be equal to the original a.vipExpires value?

I originally thought the SET operations would execute in the order specified, it seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
UPDATE coupons c, accounts a
SET c.start = a.vipExpires,
    c.end = DATE_ADD(a.vipExpires, INTERVAL c.days DAY),
    a.vipExpires = c.end
WHERE a.id = 1 AND c.id = 1;
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks! Still wonder why how SET precedence works though, or what was going on there.

Comment: @Smeagel the tables are updated in the order they're mentioned in UPDATE clause.